# Are ML.NET and Keras Neural Network models 100% compatible with each other?

Tags: c#, keras, neural-network, ml.net

Can I train a neural network model using ML.NET and then use it in Python as if it were trained using Keras, and vice versa?

Are ML.NET and Keras Neural Network models 100% compatible with each other?